# How can I use mysql to determine the Sundays for the last year?

Tags: mysql, date, date-math

I have a table where I'm currently aggregating ~200 rows per day of stats.  These stats include things like # of users, how many people using X feature, etc.

What I'd like to do is query this table so summarize the data in this way:

- **Daily over the past X days**
- **Weekly over the past year** - Take the stats from each Sunday and pulling the current day (assuming today isn't Sunday)
- **Monthly over the past X years** - Take the stats from the last day of each month and pulling the current day (assuming today isn't the last day of the month)

Columns:

- `date` is the day the data was aggregated
- `value` is the numeric value I need to show (e.g. - # of users)

I want empty records/dates to be filled with zeros so I need to use mysql to generate the dates and then join a matching record where available.  **How can I use mysql to determine the Sundays for the last year?**

Unfortunately I can't provide an example of what I have working at the moment, I'm still investigating potential solutions.  Most queries I come across are querying records by dates, not generating the dates themselves.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_stats` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `stat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `daily_stats_date_stat_unique` (`date`,`stat`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: The best option is by using a Calendar table. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Ah, thanks for adding that `mysql` tag.  The calendar table is an interesting concept, but how would using that approach help me generate the dates I'm looking for?

Comment: I've used SQL Server for the example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=22a456cc9cf5c3ace7d70549c71ed2b9

Comment: I hear ya, but that doesn't help answer the question.  This question is about using SQL to generate the correct date range, then I can join in rows where dates match.

Comment: I just showed you how to: `I want empty records/dates to be filled with zeros so I need to use mysql to generate the dates and then join a matching record where available. How can I use mysql to determine the Sundays for the last year?` But I can try to use MySql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, however I think this is what you're looking for. Check out "Date Series Generation" in this document.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series

Common Table Expressions, which enable Date Series Generation, are available as of MySQL 8.0, or Mariadb 10.2.2. If you're on an earlier version and can't upgrade, I think @McNets answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Calendar table for this and other purposes. A calendar table is always useful.

I've set up a minimal example, but usually a Calendar table has more detailed fields like, hours, minutes, ect.

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
    cDate datetime, 
    cDay int, 
    cDayOfWeek int, 
    cDayName varchar(20)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN
  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO Calendar (cDate, cDayOfWeek, cDayName) 
    VALUES (dateStart, DAYOFWEEK(dateStart), DAYNAME(dateStart));
    SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END;

CALL filldates('2018-01-01','2018-12-31');
```

> I want empty records/dates to be filled with zeros so I need to use mysql to generate the dates and then join a matching record where available. How can I use mysql to determine the Sundays for the last year?

You can use the calendar table to build this empty table in this way:

```
INSERT INTO daily_stats (`date`, `stat`, `value`, `created_at`)
SELECT
    cDate, 0, 0, now()
FROM 
    Calendar 
WHERE 
    cDayOfWeek = 7;
```

NOTE: cDayOfWeek could be different depending on first day of week in your system.

```
SELECT * FROM daily_stats LIMIT 10;
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM daily_stats LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | stat | value | created_at          | updated_at
> -: | :--------- | ---: | ----: | :------------------ | :---------
>  1 | 2018-01-06 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  2 | 2018-01-13 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  3 | 2018-01-20 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  4 | 2018-01-27 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  5 | 2018-02-03 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  6 | 2018-02-10 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  7 | 2018-02-17 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  8 | 2018-02-24 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
>  9 | 2018-03-03 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null      
> 10 | 2018-03-10 |    0 |     0 | 2019-01-19 18:16:49 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ab8f3aee1bcf5338cba1c0ef091cad9)*

Comment: This is good to know, thanks.  This doesn't really answer the question though because this is essentially the same data store I have today except the `date` column is broken out into other columns and suggests entering zeros for data missing.  If I'm missing data for a day, it means the cron didn't run or failed in some way so filling the table with empty values would need another cron in place.

Comment: For my specific needs, a solution that does this at runtime without a stored procedure would be ideal.

Comment: You only need to generate the calendar table once. You can generate a calendar table for the next 50 years